# What part of the arm is considered "below the wrist"

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

What part of the arm is considered "below the wrist" in regards to Netilat Yadayim and is off limits to touch in order to avoid impure water?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Just remember to always pour a reviis when washing and you avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a dispute if this "off limits" area starts at the knuckles, or at the wrist.

Mostly it's taken as the wrist, **where the arm begins, like a tube**.

I have not seen anybody discuss the fact that the edge of this *parallel tube* changes locations as you move your hand in a waving motion.